# Unit testing for service class which calls backendserver- angular

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, testcase, angular-test

I have a method in-service class which has a GET Call to the backend server and backendserver returns a response of people array with fields - employedID ,name, and busnTitle.

Could you help to cover the below lines?

```
searchPeople(searchWord: string): Observable<People[]> {
    return this.http.get<any>("{URL}").pipe(
        map(data => {
            if (data) {
                return data.persons.map(p => {
                    return {
                        eId: p.emplNtId,
                        name: p.name,
                        jobTitle: p.busnTitle
                    };
                });
            }
        })
    );
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the HttpTestingClient module yet?  https://angular.io/guide/testing-services#httpclienttestingmodule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Solution:
        1) people-list-mock.json
        {
            "persons": [{
                    "emplNtId:": "123456",
                    "name": "testname",
                    "busnTitle": "Tester"
                },
                {
                    "emplNtId:": "1234",
                    "name": "testname",
                    "busnTitle": "Developer"
                }
            ]
        }
        
        Added this in ts file 
        const peopleMockResponse: any = require('people-list-mock.json');
        
         it('should return an Observable<People[]> - success', () => {
  peopleService.searchPeople(mockName).subscribe(
    (people) => {
      expect(people.length).toBe(2);
    });
  const req = httpTestingController.expectOne('{URL}');
  expect(req.request.method).toBe('GET');
  req.flush(peopleMockResponse);
  httpTestingController.verify();
});

it('should not return response - failed ', () => {
  peopleService.searchPeople(mockName).subscribe(
    (people) => {
      expect(people).toBeUndefined();
    });
  const req = httpTestingController.expectOne('{URL}');
  expect(req.request.method).toBe('GET');
  req.flush(null);
  httpTestingController.verify();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply import `HttpClientTestingModule` in your `TestBed` and using the `HttpTestingController` you can simply `expect(URL)` and inject a fake response through `flush()`.

You may refer to the example from [this](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/testing/services/http/using-httptestingmodule) page.

Comment: Can you guide how to solve else part not taken warning in testcoverage???? This is testcase I have written : -->         it('should get search results', () => {
              peopleService.searchPeople('testname1').subscribe(
                res => expect(peopleMockResponse).toEqual(peopleMockResponse, 'should return expected results'),
                fail
              );
              const req = httpTestingController.expectOne('/url');
              expect(req.request.method).toEqual('GET');
              req.flush(peopleMockResponse);
              });

Comment: To cover that part, you need to mock httpTestingController such that the value of `data` in `if(data)` is falsy but in that case, I'm not sure what will your expect statement contain.